# DataTable reader loading is very slow

Tags: c#, performance, sqlite, datatable, loading

I need to fetch some data based on a keyword, the query is tested to 100% accurate, but the problem is the the loading of the `reader` is pretty slow. I have tried replacing this query with one that does not contain `inner join`s at all and the loading was pretty fast. So I wonder, since I am only selecting one column as a result, why does DataTable.Load() take so much time? Is it the `SQLite`'s `ExecuteReader` that loads the whole results and not just the one column?

Before using the DataTable, the average time of executing each `reader.Read()` was 7 seconds.

This is my code:

```cs
_database.Connect();

var selectCommand = new SQLiteCommand(
@"SELECT A.ID AS MY_ID FROM MD 
INNER JOIN TMD ON MD.ID = TMD.ID_MD 
INNER JOIN TR ON TR.ID = TMD.ID_TR 
INNER JOIN P ON P.ID = TR.ID_P 
INNER JOIN DP ON DP.ID_P = P.ID 
INNER JOIN CD ON CD.ID = DP.ID_CD 
WHERE CD.DESC = @desc"
);

selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", value);

using (DbDataReader reader = _database.ExecuteQuery(selectCommand))
{
    DataTable data = new DataTable("MyData");
    data.Load(reader);
}
_database.Disconnect();
```

Comment: It sounds like your query is simply slow. Is there a different way of accessing your tables such that you don't have to do so many joins?

Comment: I knew this was gonna hurt.. Unfortunately we need to connect the 2 tables based on one of the fields. These joins is the only connection between them, given the current DB schema.

Comment: What is `_database` and why has it methods like `Connect` and `Disconnect`? Don't reinvent the wheel. You should also use a `using-statement` for your connection to ensure that it gets "closed" as soon as possible. Is this a multithreading environment like ASP.NET?

Comment: I updated my answer. We are using 1 DB instance for each thread, and also Transactions when needed. The problem does not appear on any other query, but only on this.

Comment: @Souvlaki: Maybe there are table locks. Is Connection pooling  enabled(`Pooling=True`)? You are also not closing the connection in case of an exception, use `using` or `try/catch/finally`.

Comment: This whole block is inside try catch, which closes the connection. Pooling is not enabled, but I could try enabling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The SQLite Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) offers some hints about query optimization for SQLite.

Some items that may apply to your question:

1.) Due to the implementation in SQLite you might try to re-order the multiple joins:

> The current implementation of SQLite uses only loop joins. That is to
>   say, joins are implemented as nested loops. The default order of the
>   nested loops in a join is for the left-most table in the FROM clause to
>   form the outer loop and the right-most table to form the inner loop.

So, depending on how the JOINs are constructed there might be a difference in performance.

SQLite tries to optimize this automatically, but as far as I understood the documentation there is no guarantee for success (highlights by me):

> However, SQLite will nest the loops in a different order if doing so
>   will help it to select better indices.
>   [...]
>   Join reordering is automatic and usually works well enough that programmers
>   do not have to think about it, especially if ANALYZE has been used to gather
>   statistics about the available indices. **But occasionally some hints from the
>   programmer are needed.**

2.) Also, please note that INNER JOINS are internally converted into WHERE clauses, so any of the performance tips in the WHERE section of the document might apply, too:

> The ON and USING clauses of an inner join are converted into
>   additional terms of the WHERE clause prior to WHERE clause analysis
>   described above in paragraph 1.0. Thus with SQLite, there is no
>   computational advantage to use the newer SQL92 join syntax over the
>   older SQL89 comma-join syntax. They both end up accomplishing exactly
>   the same thing on inner joins.

3.) You might consider to select more columns in your statement, if there are any indexes on them:

> It is not necessary for every column of an index to appear in a WHERE
>   clause term in order for that index to be used. But there **can not be
>   gaps in the columns of the index that are used.**

Comment: All joins are built on primary keys, I think that this solves the issue about indexing, but I'm really trying to think if 1+2 could be life savers for my case.

Comment: I used `ANALYZE` before my sql command and the query was executed pretty fast. So, considering that you provided the correct direction for this specific problem, you get the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think this happens due a nature of SQLite and great number of joins.

Try to refactor database scheme, like denormalize data for faster access.

Comment: Does "nature of SQLite" mean that the expected results are different than the currently returned?

Comment: @Souvlaki: I mean that SQLite doesn't support a good load for such number of joins, also you may have a large file what degrades the resulting permanence as well.

Comment: Even though that the query is pretty fast on Navicat?

Comment: I think that you are correct. SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader() is the bottle-neck.